# Where can I find the original source file from the ImgTagHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I want to override the default ASP.Net Core Image TagHelper (ImgTagHelper), but can't find the original source. Where can I find it?

Related doc: [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/image-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: Is it [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/ImageTagHelper.cs)?

Comment: Thanks! I knew it must be easy, but I simply couldn't find it...

Comment: Here is all tag helpers https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers